# How to use multiple filter on Lucene Analyzer (Lucene 4.4)

Tags: java, filter, lucene, analyzer

I'm trying to apply more than one filter on the TokenStream in my customized analyzer. Following is the code:

```java
public class CustomizeAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
//code omitted

@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new LetterTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_44, reader);              
    TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, source);                
    filter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, filter, stopWords);                  
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, new PorterStemFilter(source));
}                                              
}
```

However, the LowerCaseFilter won't be used. I literally follow the documentation [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html).
Can someone please explain me how to make it work?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is in the last line.  You create a chain of filters, and then short circuit it in the return statement by passing back `new PorterStemFilter(source)`, which is a stem filter sitting directly on the tokenizer, rather than the filters earlier in the chain.  This should be:

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new LetterTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_44, reader);              
    TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, source);                
    filter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, filter, stopWords);                  
    filter = new PorterStemFilter(filter);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
}
```

Comment: that's a good catch. I cannot believe I made that mistake :( I think I need to take a rest now. Thank you very much, femtoRgon.